# Unable to access JSON data

Tags: json

I am having an issue whereby I am unable to access the following JSON with the below code. I can see the JSON in my network viewer and there are no errors, but nothing runs in the apiReturn function and I can't figure out why.

```
/**/
({
   "batchcomplete": "",
  "query": {
    "normalized": [{
      "from": "mouse",
      "to": "Mouse"
    }],
    "pages": {
      "18845": {
        "pageid": 18845,
        "ns": 0,
        "title": "Mouse",
        "extract": "<p>A <b>mouse</b> (plural: <b>mice</b>) is a small rodent characteristically having a pointed snout, small rounded ears, a body-length scaly tail and a high breeding rate. The best known mouse species is the common house mouse (<i>Mus musculus</i>). It is also a popular pet.</p>"
      }
    }
  }
})


$.getJSON("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&origin=*&format=json&exsentences=3&prop=extracts&titles=Main+Page&callback=&titles=mouse", function(apiReturn){
        var valueText = apiReturn.query.pages[18845].extract;
        console.log(valueText);
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't JSON, it's JSONP. The reason it's not working is that you have a blank `callback` parameter in the query string. Change `&callback=&titles=mouse` to `&callback=?&titles=mouse` (note the `?` after `callback=`) and jQuery will handle it for you correctly. E.g.:

```
$.getJSON("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&origin=*&format=json&exsentences=3&prop=extracts&titles=Main+Page&callback=?&titles=mouse", function(apiReturn){
// Only change is here ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^
    var valueText = apiReturn.query.pages[18845].extract;
    console.log(valueText);
});
```

More: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON and http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax

Comment: *(Sigh. If you don't see a `?` in the "Change..." sentence, hit refresh.)*

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the server is retrieving a correct json data, because your code, using external fake json works ok for me. There must be a problem with the response of the json.

```js
var fakeJsonData = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1";

$.getJSON(fakeJsonData, function(apiReturn){
  
        var valueText = apiReturn.body;
        console.log(valueText);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Please add :** &callback=? at the end of the url.

Code will look like:

```
$.getJSON("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&origin=*&format=json&exsentences=3&prop=extracts&titles=Main+Page&callback=&titles=mouse&callback=?", function(apiReturn) {
        var valueText = apiReturn.query.pages[18845].extract;
        console.log(valueText);
    })
```